# Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)). (Ros Installation)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ros, trusted

I've been trying to solve this error for 6-7 hours, but I couldn't succeed. Please help. Thank you in advance [Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtwJ2.png)

[What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895606/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)
[How can I manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d with ansible playbook since apt-key is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585303/how-can-i-manage-keyring-files-in-trusted-gpg-d-with-ansible-playbook-since-apt)
[W: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570418/w-key-is-stored-in-legacy-trusted-gpg-keyring-etc-apt-trusted-gpg-see-the-d)
[Cassandra keyring issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668008/cassandra-keyring-issue)
[Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992799/warning-apt-key-is-deprecated-manage-keyring-files-in-trusted-gpg-d-instead)
I tried almost every link similar to these but I can't solve the problem.

Comment: Duplicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992799/warning-apt-key-is-deprecated-manage-keyring-files-in-trusted-gpg-d-instead